# Image in Custom UITableViewCell moves after selection

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiimage

I have a Custom `UITableViewCell` with an `UIImage` and an `UILabel` (see screenshot below).
[image]

If I tap on the `UITableViewCell` I add a Checkmark to it, but when the checkmark is visible the `UIImage` moves to the left (see screenshot below).
[image]

Autolayout is turned off and the content mode is set to `UIViewContentModeRight` (via the Storyboard).

My Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MarkerCell *cell = (MarkerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"marker"];

    markerCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Marker *marker in self.allMarkers) {
        BOOL isEqual = NO;
        for (NSString *string in markerCategories) {
            if ([marker.identifier isEqualToString:string]) {
                isEqual = YES;
            }
        }
        if (isEqual == NO) {
            [markerCategories addObject:marker.identifier];
        }
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.opaque = NO;
    cell.backgroundView = nil;

    cell.lbMarkerName.text = markerCategories[indexPath.row];
    cell.ivIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[markerCategories[indexPath.row] lowercaseString]];

    if ([markerCategories[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Löschteich"]) cell.ivIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loeschteich"];
    if (!cell.ivIcon.image) cell.ivIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sonstige"];

    return cell;
}


   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MarkerCell *cell = (MarkerCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // handle Checkmark
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

        // remove Marker(s)
        for (Marker *marker in self.allMarkers) {
            if ([markerCategories[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:marker.identifier]) {
                [markersToShow removeObject:marker];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

        // add Marker(s)
        for (Marker *marker in self.allMarkers) {
            if ([markerCategories[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:marker.identifier]) {
                [markersToShow addObject:marker];
            }
        }
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self printMarkers];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution to my issue by my own. Because of displaying the checkmark, the `UIImage` was moved to the left through autosizing. So i just had to re-adjust autosizing.